# Оператор php

Tags: php

Подскажите оператор(а может и не оператор) языка php позволяющий делать следущее:

```
$var = 
началооперетор>>>>

//Много кода, включая функции, выводы через echo..

конец оперетора<<<<

echo $var//вывод stringа
```

Точно видел такой.. Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

```
ob_start();
//Много кода, включая функции, выводы через echo..
$var = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $var;
```

или как вариант heredoc-определение

```
$var = <<<EOS 
Много строк, но не совсем кода 
EOS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Если с кодом то используйте <<<(без пробела)EOT blah blha EOT;

[документация PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php)

Пример с документации:

> echo <<<EOT Меня зовут "$name". Я
> печатаю $foo->foo. Теперь я вывожу
> {$foo->bar[1](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php)}. Это должно вывести
> заглавную букву 'A': \x41 EOT;